# Magento 2.2.2 migration (from 1.9.2.1)

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration

How do we get Magento 2.2.2 migration (from 1.9.2.1) to skip the checks below, so that we can move past these errors?

```
2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_categorylabel does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=137
```

[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=167
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=169
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_columns does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=170
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropdown_blocks does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=171
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class seo/system_config_frontend_category does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.frontend_model for attribute_id=201
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class seo/system_config_source_category does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=201
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class seo/system_config_source_metarobots does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=202
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class seo/system_config_source_canonical does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=205
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_helper_grid_columns does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=169
[2017-12-15 15:19:24][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_helper_dropdown_blocks does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=171

Answer (score 0):

Add this to class-map.xml

<rename>
        <from>ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_categorylabel</from>
        <to />
    </rename>